# Golang Driver or HTTP?

Tags: http, go, driver, arangodb

Just wondering if anyone can help me understand the advantages of talking to Arango via HTTP or the driver? In my case the GoLang driver.

Aside from the few milliseconds overhead per request,would I experience a big difference in performance?

I like the concurrency attributes of using HTTP Requests, since my main tools all make HTTP communication very easy.

Thanks for any insights on this subject.

Comment: What driver do you use?

Comment: I haven't used one yet...trying to decide which way to go. thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick scanning through the 3 recommended drivers shows they use HTTP under the hood.
So using them will not give you big difference in DB interaction, but may be more comfortable for development.